# Is it allowed to ask whether there is a synonym of a specific Russian expression\idiom in English?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I have a question regarding specific saying in Russian. I'd like to know if there is a saying\expression in English which has a similar meaning. Is such question fits this site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Q&A is ***not*** for questions about English that are targeted to Russian speaking audience. Therefore, the type of questions you're talking about should ***not*** be welcome on RLU. They must be welcome on ELU, with the caveat that you should not only post the Russian word (so that Russian speakers can see it) but also explain it thoroughly so that others can answer your question as well.

Comment: See my edit, Armen.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit**: I've just noticed that in the [definition phase](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/10848?phase=definition), these questions were highly upvoted.

Technically we should consider them on-topic, if they're the same kind you were referring to (I think so). In order to deem them as off topic, a Meta question should be proposed to ask the community opinion.

---

Initially I was in favor, and actually I'm not against, but this would be easier for the users in EL&U perhaps? I think that here for example, you could post the opposite: English to Russian saying correspondence.

Remember that if you ask it on one site, you theoretically cannot post the same question on another site. One of them will be deleted/migrated and merged with the other one. So choose the best site for your question, don't *force* it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just wonder how many Russian speakers are there on EL&U and what are the chances that one of them will see my question and actually know the answer... That's the reason why I think it'll best asking it here rather than EL&U..

Comment: There are some there... But the fact is that you need to look for those that know best the "target" language.

Comment: @EugeneS See my edit.